# Коррупция, задача на жадный алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите мне, пожалуйста, решить эту задачу, а также объяснить, как получается ответ в первом тесте.

> Коррупция
>
> С целью борьбы с теневой экономикой банк решил внедрить объединение `N`
>   счетов фирмы в один. За одну операцию объединяются 2 счета и банк
>   автоматически перечисляет на свой счет `Р`% от суммы объединения за
>   выполнение операции и закрытие одного из счетов. Какая наибольшая
>   сумма может остаться на счету фирмы? На каждом из счетов до внедрения
>   политики объединения было не более чем `G` грн.
>
> Входные данные:
>
> - В первой строке 2 числа: количество счетов `N` и процент отчислений `P`.
> - Во второй строке `N` чисел: сумма на каждом из счетов фирмы.
>
> Выходные данные:
>
> - Наибольшая сумма, которая может остаться на счету.
>
> ```
> 2 ≤ N ≤ 100000
> 0 ≤ Р ≤ 20
> 0 ≤ G ≤ 10000
> ```
>
> Входные данные #1:
>
> ```
> 4 5
> 1000 1100 1200 1300
> ```
>
> Выходные данные #1:
>
> ```
> 4151.50
> ```

Comment: можете объяснить как получается ответ в первом тесте ? Всё перепробовал.

Comment: а лучше если вы покажете как решить эту задачу ,чтобы технику решения задач на жадные алгоритмы посмотреть .

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это просьба сделать работу за автора (решить задачу с нуля)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как получается ответ.
Думаю, алгоритм отсюда тоже понятен.

```js
// 1000 1100 1200 1300
console.log((1000 + 1100) * .95)
// 1200 1300 1995
console.log((1200 + 1300) * .95)
// 1995 2375
console.log((1995 + 2375) * .95)
// 4151.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Полное решение задачи будет содержать кучу или иную аналогичную по функционалу структуру (мульти-сет например).

1 - сливать нужно всегда 2 счёта с минимальным кол-вом денег (строго не доказываю).

2 - найти эти 2 счёта можно выталкиванием из кучи.

3 - затолкать что осталось (за вычетом сбора) обратно в кучу.

P.S. G дано в условии, чтобы не боялись переполнения 32-битного типа.

Comment: 32-битного? Там же промежуточные результаты всё равно дробные. Или следует как-то потом считать процент от суммы?

Comment: Судя по тому, что решение не проходит большинство тестов, там какие-то заморочки с вычислениями - если брать double, а потом округлять до копеек - не работает... Похоже, фокус там именно в этом расчете...

Comment: @Harry, интересно. А точно жадно сливать верно? Не может быть подвоха?

Comment: @Harry а ссылку на задачу можно?

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/21

Comment: Я использовал `set`, уже примерно так - http://ideone.com/oeAVOs Пробовал разные варианты...

Comment: @Harry, `set` - это неверно, надо `multiset`, потому что могут быть равные суммы.

Comment: @Qwertiy да честно говоря не сильно лучше. Условие кривое - это факт.

Comment: @Qwertiy Логично. Не подумал. Ща проверим... Нет, не помогает. С 5% поднялось до 20%, и все. Попробовал считать поточнее - до 10^-7 копейки - поднялось до 50% :)

Comment: @Harry, long double и gcc (не VS)?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, я взял уже long long и считал в 10^-7 копейки, точнее - может быть переполнение. http://ideone.com/SdMygg - все равно что-то не то. Уже просто интересно, в чем же проблема? gcc или нет - неважно: проверка-то на сайте...

Comment: @pavel Скажите, если у вас получится - уже просто интересно, где ж проблема...

Comment: @Harry ничего хорошего не получилось. Вообще в олимпиадных задач **всегда** пишут условия на точность. Я так прикинул, если без округления работать, то в ответе может быть порядка 20000 знаков.

Comment: @pavel Ну, ваш ответ по крайней мере помог мне избежать развития комплекса неполноценности :) Спасибо!

Comment: @pavel Вспомнил сегодня что-то... До 75% довел путем работы с точностью до 10^-7 + округление при каждом вычислении типа `sum = ((sum+50000)/100000)*100000;` Так что там явно нужно какое-то округление хитрое, но какое?...

Comment: Ребята, получилось у кого решить или нет?